# Setting up sendmail to use aliases without a hostname? [domain name without hostname]

Tags: sendmail, aliases

I'm setting up sendmail on a machine with hostname 'foo', and FQDN 'foo.example.com'. My `/etc/aliases` contains

```
webmaster: me
me: me@somewhere-else.com
```

If I now try to send a test email, from 'foo', to 'webmaster', I find that:

1. `To: webmaster@example.com` fails (the log output shows that sendmail does not attempt to do an aliases look-up)
2. `To: webmaster@foo.example.com` succeeds (the email arrives at 'me@somewhere-else.com')
3. `To: webmaster` succeeds (sendmail expands this to 'webmaster@foo.example.com', and does a lookup)

Is there some setting in sendmail.mc that will let me use form 1, ie. the alias *without* the hostname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sendmail by default does aliases lookups for email in local email domains.
Most likely `example.com` is not treated/configured as local email domain.

To get list of configured and autoconfigured local email domains as root execute:

```
echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt
```

You can configure `example.com` as local email domain by adding it to `/etc/mail/local-host-names` file (one domain per line). Sendmail daemon requires restart or reload (sending it HUP signal) to notice the change.

Comment: Thanks - all working. This bit, anyway :)